# android-library flavor dependencies and custom source sets

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library

I have a library of shared code that is then used by an app with multiple flavors depending on where it is being published to.

I've tried using both the 1.5, 2.0 and 2.1 versions of the android plugin. Gradle 2.8, 2.10 and 2.10 respectively.

The framework defines a number of product flavours for different SKUs however I'm running into a couple of problems. There are some dependencies for third party ad providers, IAP systems etc. which should only be included in the correct SKU.

Similarly some classes are just in a flat directory and should only be included in the correct build flavor. (This is a legacy of an older build setup, we're currently trying to get everything cleaned up and moved over onto gradle correctly.)

However if I try to define a project or file dependency based on the product flavor they will not be included correctly resulting in errors. In the below example a java class referencing Sku2Utils or sku2 IAP would fail due to missing symbols or the package not existing.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 android {
     publishNonDefault true
     productFlavors {
         sku1 {
         }
         sku2 {
         }
     }

     sourceSets {
         main {
         }

         sku1 {
         }

         sku2 {
         }
     }
 }


 dependencies {
     //seems fine
     sku1Compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
     //or
     //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

     //also fine
     compile files('./some/path/common-IAP.jar')
     //project works
     compile project(':HelpfulProject')

     //doesn't function as expected?
     sku2Compile project(':Sku2Utils')

     //similarly doesn't seem to function correctly
     sku2Compile files('./some/path/sku2-IAP.jar')
 }
```

For clarity subproject locations are defined as

```
include ':Sku2Utils'
project(":Sku2Utils").projectDir = new File("../../../some/path/sku2/Sku2Utils/")
```

Then added as a dependency to the App

```
 defaultConfig.with {
    applicationId "com.companyname.awesomeapp"
 }

 android {
      productFlavors {
         sku1 {
         }
         sku2 {
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     sku1Compile project(path: ':framework', configuration: 'sku1Release')
     sku2Compile project(path: ':framework', configuration: 'sku2Release')
 }
```

I've got proguard enabled to reduce the app size, but I don't think it is causing any issues. If I remove dependencies I can get at least 1 sku building correctly without any problems I just don't seem to be able to get both working without bloating the app with unused store / ad providers.

Additionally excluding classes doesn't seem to work correctly using the sourceSets

```
 sourceSets {
      main {
           java.excludes = ['**/SomeOldFile.java']
      }
      sku1 {
           java {
                excludes =  ['**/Sku2Class.java', '**/Sku2Helper.java']
           }
      }
      sku2 {
           java.excludes =  ['**/Sku1Class.java', '**/Sku1Helper.java'] 
      }
 }
```

Excluding files using the main set functions as expected but trying to exclude classes from specific flavors doesn't seem to be used.

Would it be more correct to split the above classes into different directories /sku1/ and /sku2/ then define them as java source directories?

(white list the files we need rather than including everything then stripping out later?)